# Meteor/Mongo DB $gte operator not working on find();

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to make a query so that I only return the 'productos' that are on the current 'categoria', they also need to have the 'stock.cantidad' field greater or equal than 1 and the 'stock.idCedis' equal to a specific value, and this is how I am trying to do it:

```
return Productos.find(
        {
          idCategoria: Router.current().params._id,
          "stock.cantidad":{$gte: 1},
          "stock.idCedis":idCedis
        });
```

I checked and the "stock.idCedis":idCedis is working just fine displaying the 'productos' that have that specific 'idCedis', but what I am having problems with is the "stock.cantidad":{$gte: 1}, part because I don't know why Meteor or Mongo DB for that matter are just ignoring it.

The schema for the stock part of 'productos' that I am currently using is this:

```
stock: {
    type: [Object]
  },
    "stock.$.cantidad": {
      type: Number,
      label: "Cantidad de Stock",
      min: 0
    },
    "stock.$.idCedis": {
      type: String,
      label: "Centro de Distribución"
    },
```

So I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or any other way I could make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Since *stock.$.cantitad* is an array try *$elemMatch*:

```
return Productos.find(
        {
          idCategoria: Router.current().params._id,
          "stock.cantidad":{$elemMatch {$gte: 1}},
          "stock.idCedis":idCedis
        });
```

The [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) indicate that you shouldn't need to do this when there's only a single query condition but given how Meteor interacts with mongo I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Michael Floyd, what I needed was that $elemMatch query operator, but for some reason your code did not worked form me, what worked was this:

```
Productos.find(
        {
          idCategoria: Router.current().params._id,
          stock: { $elemMatch: { idCedis: idCedis, cantidad: { $gte: 0 } } }
        });
```